# How can I view a page that is cached in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

How can I view a page that is cached in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Just type this line in the firefox address bar.

```
about:cache?device=memory
```

these are the cache entries.

Comment: This does not display a page.  Instead it displays a list of links that link to pages of information about the associated pages.